# How to compare similarities between paragraphs NLP

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, doc2vec

I've been experimenting with NLP, and use the Doc2Vec model.

The aim of my objective, is a forum suggested question feature. For example, If a user types a question it will compare the vector to other questions already asked. So far this has worked ok in the sense of comparing a question to another asked question.

However, I would like to extend this to comparing the body of the question. For example, just like stackoverflow, I'm writing a the description to my question.

I understand that doc2vec represents sentences through paragraph ids. So for my question example I spoke about first, each sentence will be a unique paragraph id. However, with paraphs i.e the body to the question, sentences will have the same id as other sentences apart of the same paragraph.

```py
para = 'This is a sentence. This is another sentence'
[['This','is','a','sentence',tag=[1]], ['This','is','another','sentence',tag=[1]]
```

I'm wondering how to go about doing this. How can i input a corpus like so:

```py
['It is a nice day today. I wish I was outside in the sun. But I need to work.']
```

and compare that to another paragraph like this:

```py
['It is a lovely day today. The sun is shining outside today. However, I am working.']
```

In which I would expect a very close similarity  between the two. Does similarity get calculated by sentence to sentence, rather then paragraph to paragraph? i.e.

```py
cosine_sim(['It is a nice day today'],['It is a lovely day today.]
```

and do this for the other sentences and average out the similarity scores?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
What I am confused about is using the above sentences, say the vectors are like so

```py
sent1 = [0.23,0.1,0.33...n]
sent2 = [0.78,0.2,-0.6...n]
sent3 = [0.55,-0.5,0.9...n]

#Avergae out these vectors

para = [0.5,0.2,0.3...n]
```

and using this vector compare to another paragraph using the same process.

Comment: please forgive me if out of scope of your needs, but SpaCy is great for doing similarity matching. A must have for NLP experimentations
take a look https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Answer (score 0):

I'll presume you're talking about the `Doc2Vec` model in the Python Gensim library - based on the word2vec-like 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm. (There are many alternate ways to turn a text into a vector, and sometimes other ways, including the very-simple approach of averaging word-vectors together, gets called 'Doc2Vec' also.)

`Doc2Vec` has no internal idea of sentences or paragraphs. It just considers texts: lists of word tokens. So you decide what-sized chunks of text to provide, and to associate with `tag` keys: multiword fragments, sentences, paragraphs, sections, chapters, articles, books, whatever.

Every `tag` you provide during initial bulk training will have an associated vector trained up, and stored in the model, based on the lists-of-words that you provided alongside it. So, you can retrieve those vectors from training via:

```
d2v_model.dv[tag]
```

You can also use that trained, frozen model to infer new vectors for new lists-of-words:

```
d2v_model.infer_vector(list_of_words)
```

(Note: these words should be preprocessed/tokenized the same was as those during training, and any words not known to the model from training will be silently ignored.)

And, once you have vectors for two different texts, from whatever method, you can compare them via cosine-similarity.

For creating your doc-vectors, you might want to run the `question` & `body` together into one text. (If the `question` is more important, you could even consider training on a pseudotext that's repeats the `question` more than once, for example both before and after the `body`.) Or you might want to treat them separately, so that some downstream process can weight `question`->`question` similarities differently than `body`->`body` or `question`->`body`. What's best for your data & goals usually has to be determined via experimentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm a little lost about how to "compare 2 paragraphs". I know how to compare 2 sentences, but from what I have read Doc2Vec requires a tag to represent the paragraph the sentence comes from. However, there is no implementation of how to compare 2 paragraphs together.

Comment: Hence, I proposed do the sentence vectors get averaged out ? I will update my question to re reflect better what I mean

Comment: There is no difference between a 'sentence' and 'paragraph' in `Doc2Vec`. They're both just lists-of-words. If you know how to compare 2 sentences, just do the exact same thing with all the words of a paragraph instead of all the words of a sentence. (In working with `Doc2Vec`, I suggest banishing the words 'sentence' and 'paragraph' from your thinking. Instead, consider lists-of-words, which you could call 'texts' or 'documents', if it helps.)

Comment: Thanks, so basically my misunderstanding is, for Doc2Vec you feed in a list of words into the model (which is a sentence typically), however you can combine multiple sentences to one list of words and input into the model?

Comment: for example ``['It is sunny today. I should go outside then. What a day!']`` - in a sentence embedding this would be 3 tokenized lists. Is it possible to remove the punctuation (i.e. full stops etc.) and represent 1 list with all the tokenized words and feed that into the doc2vec?

Comment: Why would that be 3 tokenized lists? It's 12 words. (15 words if you choose to turn the punctuation marks into standalone pseudoword tokens, which some work with these sorts of algorithms chooses to do.) `Doc2Vec` doesn't know what sentences are, so if you're thinking in terms of sentences, you're not matching what it expects, & you're doing extra unnecessary work compared to what it needs. Just don't do that. (& if for some reason it's been broken into sentences outside your control, you're free to just concatenate those 3 lists-of-words into 1-list-of-words, so it's what `Doc2Vec` expects.)

Comment: Sweet thanks. So for example if i text summarize to say 500 words, I can feed this into a BERT model as an example (I think 512 tokens is the limit) and it will give me a vector?

Comment: No, I don't think you'd feed `Doc2Vec` vectors into a BERT model. I recommend asking a separate question about feeding text into a BERT model.